# Why does this img div display in front of my other blocks?

Tags: html, css

I applied `display: block` to my other divs but my image is displayed in front. I thought `display: block` would force a line break. Why is my image in front?

https://codepen.io/El_Escandalo/pen/PoPzXPZ?editors=1100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your `.container` div is limited to `height: 200px;`. Erase that to allow its height to adjust to the contents, and your image container will be below it.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an extra closed  after container C.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


.container {
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: none;
}

.a {
  height: 100px;
  width: 33%;
  background: red;
  display: block;
   padding: none;
  border: 10px solid purple;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.b {
  height: 100px;
  width: 33%;
  background: green;
  display: block;
    padding: none;
  border: 10px solid purple;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}

.c {
  height: 100px;
  width: 33%;
  background: blue;
  display: block;
  padding: none;
  border: 10px solid purple;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.d {
  border: 25px solid pink;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75vw;
    height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  }

.d img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="c"></div>
<div class="img-cont">
  <div class="d">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/03/26/10/51/norway-4970019_1280.jpg" alt="view">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why change the markup if  there's no problem with it ?

Comment: There was a problem with it, as I mentioned, there was a stray closing div tag.

Comment: Sorry I have an extra what after container c? Thanks

Comment: After <div class = "c"></div> you have an extra </div>. Deleting that from your mark up solved the issue. So the snippet I've attached literally only has that div tag removed.

Comment: Thanks. I believe that div was closing my first container (.container) before I created the 2nd container (img-cont).